# How can I place a view in middle-bottom center of Card View?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have this layout so far:

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="150dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/viewA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.CardView> 

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>
```

But **how can I place the button in the middle-bottom (of the width)** of the Coordinator layout and have a result like this? :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `linearlayout` inside the `CardView` and use it in the attribute `app:layout_anchor` of the FAB, something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".vistas.fragments.FragmentDatosTab">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_iniciar_sesion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linearlayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image: FAB in middle-bottom of cardview]